# How can I discretize a set of values in WEKA?

Tags: weka, decision-tree, discretization

I have a set of integer values from 1 to 50 and I´d like to discretize this set in order to work with ranges instead of individual values (they are a huge amount of numbers for a decision tree). Let´s say I want a range from 1 to 25 and another range from 26 to 50. I´ ve tried with the Discretize filter but I don´t get anything to work.

Do you know how to do this in WEKA?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set them as I did in this screenshot:

[image]

Here I used the *ionosphere.arff* dataset. AttributeIndecices "1" means "column 1".

Comment: But is it possible to specify the labels of the bins and not only the number of bins but also the range of values that go in to each bin?